# addEventListener using for loop and passing values

Tags: javascript, for-loop, addeventlistener

I'm trying to add event listener to multiple objects using a for loop, but end up with all listeners targeting the same object --> the last one.

If I add the listeners manually by defining boxa and boxb for every instance, it works. I guess it's the addEvent for-loop that's not working the way I hoped for. Maybe I use the wrong approach altogether.

Example using 4 of the class="container"
Trigger on container 4 works the way it´s supposed to.
Trigger on container 1,2,3 trigger event on container 4, but only if trigger has already been activated.

```js
// Function to run on click:
function makeItHappen(elem, elem2) {
  var el = document.getElementById(elem);
  el.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  var el2 = document.getElementById(elem2);
  el2.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}

// Autoloading function to add the listeners:
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("triggerClass");

for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i += 2) {
  var k = i + 1;
  var boxa = elem[i].parentNode.id;
  var boxb = elem[k].parentNode.id;

  elem[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    makeItHappen(boxa, boxb);
  }, false);
  elem[k].addEventListener("click", function() {
    makeItHappen(boxb, boxa);
  }, false);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one" id="box1">
    <p class="triggerClass">some text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="two" id="box2">
    <p class="triggerClass">some text</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="one" id="box3">
    <p class="triggerClass">some text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="two" id="box4">
    <p class="triggerClass">some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its because of closures :D ...but why don't you add the event listener on the parent element rather than adding to it to each child element?

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Closures! :D

This fixed code works as you intended:

```js
// Function to run on click:
function makeItHappen(elem, elem2) {
    var el = document.getElementById(elem);
    el.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    var el2 = document.getElementById(elem2);
    el2.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}

// Autoloading function to add the listeners:
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("triggerClass");

for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i += 2) {
    (function () {
        var k = i + 1;
        var boxa = elem[i].parentNode.id;
        var boxb = elem[k].parentNode.id;
        elem[i].addEventListener("click", function() { makeItHappen(boxa,boxb); }, false);
        elem[k].addEventListener("click", function() { makeItHappen(boxb,boxa); }, false);
    }()); // immediate invocation
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one" id="box1">
    <p class="triggerClass">some text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="two" id="box2">
    <p class="triggerClass">some text</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="one" id="box3">
    <p class="triggerClass">some text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="two" id="box4">
    <p class="triggerClass">some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Why does this fix it?

```
for(var i=0; i < elem.length; i+=2){
    var k = i + 1;
    var boxa = elem[i].parentNode.id;
    var boxb = elem[k].parentNode.id;

    elem[i].addEventListener("click", function(){makeItHappen(boxa,boxb);}, false);
    elem[k].addEventListener("click", function(){makeItHappen(boxb,boxa);}, false);
}
```

Is actually non-strict JavaScript. It's interpretted like this:

```
var i, k, boxa, boxb;
for(i=0; i < elem.length; i+=2){
    k = i + 1;
    boxa = elem[i].parentNode.id;
    boxb = elem[k].parentNode.id;

    elem[i].addEventListener("click", function(){makeItHappen(boxa,boxb);}, false);
    elem[k].addEventListener("click", function(){makeItHappen(boxb,boxa);}, false);
}
```

Because of [variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting), the `var` declarations get moved to the top of the scope. Since JavaScript doesn't have block scope (`for`, `if`, `while` etc.) they get moved to the top of the function. **Update:** as of ES6 you can use [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) to get block scoped variables.

When your code runs the following happens: in the `for` loop you add the click callbacks and you assign `boxa`, but its value gets overwritten in the next iteration. When the click event fires the callback runs and the value of `boxa` is *always* the last element in the list.

Using a closure (closing the values of `boxa`, `boxb` etc) you bind the value to the scope of the click handler.

---

Code analysis tools such [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) or [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) will be able to catch suspicious code like this. If you're writing a lot of code it's worthwhile to take the time to learn how to use these tools. Some IDEs have them built-in.

Comment: @musefan they are the problem, because of variable hoisting. Please see my explanation.

Comment: should `}(i, k))` be `})(i, k)`?

Comment: *Is actually invalid JavaScript.*: If it was invalid, it would not parse or execute. *Using the closure like I showed you, you do get the behaviour you were expecting*: Correct, but the important point is that you are *executing* a function inside the loop, which creates a new scope.

Comment: @Wayne: Either way is fine. Personally I find the first one more readable.

Comment: @Felix potato potato, changed wording to _non-strict_. @Wayne either works but `}())` is my preference.

Comment: @Halcyon This is a really great explanation on closures!  Favorited this question and answer.

Comment: So well explained, thank you so much !

Comment: up vote for mentioning let option

Answer (score 17):

You can use Function Binding.You dont need use closures.See below:

**Before**:

```
function addEvents(){
   var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("triggerClass");

   for(var i=0; i < elem.length; i+=2){
      var k = i + 1;
      var boxa = elem[i].parentNode.id;
      var boxb = elem[k].parentNode.id;

      elem[i].addEventListener("click", function(){makeItHappen(boxa,boxb);}, false);
      elem[k].addEventListener("click", function(){makeItHappen(boxb,boxa);}, false);
   }
}
```

**After**:

```
function addEvents(){
   var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("triggerClass");

   for(var i=0; i < elem.length; i+=2){
        var k = i + 1;
      var boxa = elem[i].parentNode.id;
      var boxb = elem[k].parentNode.id;
      elem[i].addEventListener("click", makeItHappen.bind(this, boxa, boxb), false);
      elem[k].addEventListener("click", makeItHappen.bind(this, boxa, boxb), false);
   }
}
```

Comment: I like this solution. It is very clear and readable.

Comment: i like this too. thanks.

Comment: Nice solution, easy to implement and works. Would you be able to provide some more insights in how/why it works? (I know I can just search for it, but it would be nice to have 1 or 2 paragraphs directly here for the ones who end up here in the future.)

Comment: I literally have no idea how this works but it does, and boy is it clean! Thanks very muchie!

Answer (score 15):

You facing the scope/closure problem as `function(){makeItHappen(boxa,boxb);}` *boxa* and *boxb* references then always the last one element(s).

To solve the issue:

```
function makeItHappenDelegate(a, b) {
  return function(){
      makeItHappen(a, b)
  }
}

// ...
 elem[i].addEventListener("click", makeItHappenDelegate(boxa,boxb), false);
```

Comment: This is essentially the same solution. You create a closure in `makeItHappenDelegate` by returning a function that is bound to the actual values of `boxa` and `boxb`.

Comment: yes, but it is much better as we do not create self invoking function on each loop. Yes we create the delegate, but this is minimal overhead.

Comment: In this case I doubt the (extremely minimal) performance overhead outweighs the readability benefits. If you have long lists, say 100.000+ you might see a performance benefit but below that I really wouldn't worry about it. Readability is far more important.

Comment: Hm, delegation is much more better approach, even in sense of readability and maintainability. **S**OLID

Comment: I do agree, I find this much more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 2):

It's because of closures.

Check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops_A_common_mistake

The sample code and your code is essentially the same, it's a common mistake for those don't know "closure".

To put it simple, when your create a handler function inside `addEvents()`, it does not just accesses the variable `i` from the `addEvents()`'s environment, but it also "remembers" `i`.

And because your handler "remembers" `i`, the variable `i` won't vanish after `addEvents()` was executed.

So when the handler is called, it will use the `i` but the variable `i` is now, after the for-loop, 3.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem a while ago.
I solved it by using a "adds" function outside the loop, to assign events, and it worked perfectly.

Your script should look like.

```js
function addEvents(){
  var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("triggerClass");
  for(var i=0; i < elem.length; i+=2){
    var k = i + 1;
    var boxa = elem[i].parentNode.id;
    var boxb = elem[k].parentNode.id;

//- edit ---------------------------|
    adds(boxa, boxb);
  }
}
//- adds function ----|
function adds(obj1, obj2){
  obj1.addEventListener("click", function(){makeItHappen(obj1, obj2);}, false);
  obj2.addEventListener("click", function(){makeItHappen(obj1, obj2);}, false);
}
//- end edit -----------------------|

function makeItHappen(elem, elem2){
  var el = document.getElementById(elem);
  el.style.transform = "flip it";
  var el2 = document.getElementById(elem2);
  el2.style.transform = "flip it";
}
```