# Javascript dynamic function creation Google Maps Markers object loop

Tags: javascript, google-maps-markers, dynamic-allocation

Simply put, I am trying to dynamically create a marker and corresponding label for each property of in the loop. The label will contain the time-stamp.

However, I am fairly stuck on figuring out how to get the on-click function to remain bound to it's respective marker. The infowindow variable as well.

I have tried using a counter and creating an array of variables to reference each function. I have also tried eval and creating new variables within the global window

`window["foo" + counter]`

unsuccessfully. With all variations of this that I have tried the code has broken or resulted in all triggers/infowindows being bound to the same property.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated. I think I am just missing some depth on understanding variable/object scope. This base code results in all markers appearing and the final label (since the previous ones are overwritten) as depicted below.
[image: image of current state]

### variables:

```
prop = string representing long,lat coordinates
obj[prop] = An ISOformat timestamp
```

Rest of the code taken from [marker Labels Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple-max)

```
    for (var prop in obj) {
        // skip loop if the property is from prototype
        if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;


        var templocs = prop.split(",").map(Number);
        console.log(templocs[0]);
        var temppos = new google.maps.LatLng(templocs[0], templocs[1]);

        var mark = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:temppos,
            map: map,
            animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,

        });
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "date taken: " + obj[prop],
            maxWidth: 200
        }); 

        mark.addListener('click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, mark);
        });       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var cnt = 0;
    var infowindow = [];
    var mark = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    for (var prop in obj) {
        // skip loop if the property is from prototype
        if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;

        var templocs = prop.split(",").map(Number);
        console.log(templocs[0]);
        var temppos = new google.maps.LatLng(templocs[0], templocs[1]);

        infowindow[cnt] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "date taken: " + obj[prop],
            maxWidth: 200
        });         


        mark[cnt] = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: temppos,
            map: map,
            animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,

        });


/*      mark[cnt].addListener('click', function() {
            infowindow[cnt].open(map, mark);
        });     */  

        google.maps.event.addListener(mark[cnt], 'click', (function(markerrr, cnt) {
          return function() {
            infowindow[cnt].open(map, mark[cnt]);
          }
        })(mark[cnt], cnt));
        bounds.extend(mark[cnt].getPosition());

        cnt++;
    }
```

Fixed. This post is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27794288/cannot-read-property-open-of-undefined-google-maps-infowindow-loop)

Issue had to do with closure.