# addEventListener doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener

First let me explain you briefly what I'm trying to do, I have an unordered list with like 10 elements when the page first loads, then whenever the user scroll the list and reach the bottom it loads 10 more elements. I've done this with ajax and it works fine, the problem is that I want that the element clicked by the user has to appear in an input field and I don't know why this doesn't work:

```
function loadCod(){
$.ajax({
    url: '<%= request.getContextPath() %>/GetMoreCod',
    error: function(){
        var s = "CONNECTION'S ERROR";
        alert(s);
    },
    success: function(data){
        if(data == null) return null;
        if(data.indexOf('|') == -1) return new Array(buffer);
        var arrayCod = data.split('|');

        for(var i = 0; i< arrayCod.length; i++)
        {
            var ul = document.getElementById("menu");
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            $("li").each(function()
                {
                var $li = $(this);
                $li.css("cursor","pointer");       
            });
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            a.textContent = arrayCod[i];
            a.addEventListener("click",function(){  //HERE IS THE PROBLEM
            $("#codField").val(arrayCod[i]);},false); 
            li.appendChild(a);
            ul.appendChild(li);
        }

    },
    type: "GET"
});
```

}

Which is strange for me is if here `$("#codField").val(arrayCod[i])` instead of `arrayCod[i]` I put something like `"Hello"` it does work and it appears in the input.

Another example is that if I write `alert(arrayCod[i])` before the `addEventListener` it shows me the correct value but if I do this inside the `addEventListener` it shows me nothing.

[EDIT] I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19586137/addeventlistener-using-for-loop-and-passing-values) but it still doesn't work

Comment: I think this is because when the event listener is triggered, the inside of that anonymous `function() {}` is in the global scope (on the document) whereas `arrayCod` is defined in the scope of the success function of the ajax call. What do you get if you put `console.log(this);` in the anonymous function?

Comment: Is this the exact code you test? Because if so then the console would tell you that there is a syntax error at `$("#codField").val(arrayCod[i)`.  Something like `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

Comment: When your listener is called, i will be arrayCod.length and thus arrayCod[i]  will be undefined. @RobLang - that is incorrect: arrayCod will be in scope because a function's scope is based on where it is *defined*. The value of `this` is separate to scope, and in this case should be the clicked element.

Comment: Take a look at: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: `addEventListener` is a standard method and works properly.

Comment: if i write console.log(this); it gives me that: <a>150F24</a>, 150F24 is the correct code.

Comment: You have to use Javascript Closure here.  a.addEventListener("click",function(i){ .................. }(i)); As addEvenListener is just for registering the event and the index i will have the last value. You have to pass the 'i' to the function using closure.

Comment: Change your code to this Closure: a.addEventListener("click",function(i){  
            $("#codField").val(arrayCod[i]); }(i),false);

Comment: @ShwethaU Doesn't work

Comment: @t.niese could you re-open the thread please? I cheked the other thread but the problem still there

Comment: @Nurul You need show how did try to apply a closure inside of the loop. As long as you don't show that there will be no reason to reopen, because the linked answer should solve the problem.

Comment: @Nurul Use this closure syntax: (function(i){
  a.addEventListener("click",function(){  
     $("#codField").val(arrayCod[i]);},false); 
    })(i);

Comment: @ShwethaU Thanks a lot mate, it does work

Comment: I am happy it wroked, please vote up my answer :)