# get this node value after added event listener by looping

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have several textareas, and I want to add event listener to each textarea. When I type inside a textarea, I need to console the value typed inside it. I just can't figure out how to refer "this" to each textarea called in looping when being added event listener. The code below results in "undefined" in the browser console. Maybe you can set it right. Appricated the help. Thank you very much.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    var char_max_inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.char_max');
    for (var i = 0; i < char_max_inputs.length; i++){
        var max_char = char_max_inputs[i].getAttribute("max_char");
        var counter_id = char_max_inputs[i].getAttribute("counter_id");     
        char_max_inputs[i].addEventListener("keyup", function(){count_char(counter_id, max_char);}, false);
    }
});

function count_char(counter_id, max_char) {
    console.log(this.value);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [addEventListener using for loop and passing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19586137/addeventlistener-using-for-loop-and-passing-values)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can solve it like this by using [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var char_max_inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.char_max');
  for (var i = 0; i < char_max_inputs.length; i++) {
    var max_char = char_max_inputs[i].getAttribute("max_char");
    var counter_id = char_max_inputs[i].getAttribute("counter_id");
    char_max_inputs[i].addEventListener("keyup", count_char.bind(char_max_inputs[i], counter_id, max_char), false);
  }
});

function count_char(counter_id, max_char) {
  console.log(this.value);
}
```

```html
<textarea class="char_max"></textarea>
<textarea class="char_max"></textarea>
<textarea class="char_max"></textarea>
```

`this` can be very confusing in JavaScript, if not read about properly. An excellent resource to understand it is [here](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md)

**UPDATE**

As pointed out in the comments, the example using call and bind together was incomplete. Removing it.

Comment: Using the .call method is the simplest way. It works. Thank you very much!

Comment: I would suggest you use the second method. That way you don't need to worry about the problems being mentioned in the other answer

Comment: yes i have turned to using "bind", using "call" method results some bug