# Toggle Classname using document.getElementsByClassName - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a left sidebar menu which has submenus, i want each menu item to toggle a classname "active" so the submenu will open i have CSS for it.

The thing is i am using `document.getElementsByClassName` to select and iterate all of the menu items and is only working for the first element, i have been searching and it has something to do with closures and i am trying different solutions but its not working.

i am making the function so i can use it to toggle a classname of another div and not the one clicked, in that case i use and ID.

```
var toggleClassname = function (otherDiv, sameDiv) {
    var divToToggleClass;
//are we going to use ID and toggle the classname of another div ?
    if (sameDiv) {
        divToToggleClass = this;
    } else {
        divToToggleClass = document.getElementById(otherDiv);
    }
    console.log(divToToggleClass);
    var className = divToToggleClass.className + ' ';

    if (~className.indexOf(' active ')) {
        divToToggleClass.className = className.replace(' active ', '');
    } else {
        divToToggleClass.className += ' active';
    }
};
var MenuItemsArray = document.getElementsByClassName("classOfMyMenuItems");

for (var i = 0; i < subMenuItemsArray.length; i++) {
    MenuItemsArray[i].addEventListener('click', function () { toggleClassname(null, true) }, false);
}
```

i have been trying using `[].forEach.call` or wrapping the function in another that returns the function, not working.

I am doing this in pure javascript, cant use the new `.classList.toggle` i would also use attachEvent to be more backwards compatible (old IE).

Comment: What is `toggleClassnameWrapper()`?

Comment: edited, sorry that was something i tried, it should just call `toggleClassname `

Comment: OK. Currently `toggleClassname` is only receiving the arguments `null` and `true`, so it doesn't know what the current element is and its `this` is *not* the current element so `divToToggleClass = this` isn't doing what you want. You could fix this by using `toggleClassname.call(this, null, true)`, to set its `this` to the same `this` as in the event handler (which *is* the right element), or you could just add another argument to the function to take a reference to the current element.

Comment: yup, that is working, but its not clear to me, doesnt know which is "this" isnt the element that was "clicked" since i am using ".addEventListener" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that within your `toggleClassname()` function `this` is *not* equal to the clicked element. It will actually be either `undefined` or `window` depending on whether your code is running in strict mode or not.

A click handler bound with `addEventListener()` will have `this` set to the clicked element, so within the following anonymous function:

```
function () { toggleClassname(null, true) }
```

...the value of `this` is the element in question. But then you call `toggleClassname()` and don't pass it a reference to the clicked element or set *its* `this` value. You can explicitly set it using `.call()`:

```
function () { toggleClassname.call(this, null, true) }
```

Further reading:

- [`this` in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)
- [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Answer (score 0):

This answer might help you:

[addEventListener using for loop and passing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19586137/addeventlistener-using-for-loop-and-passing-values)

Without going too deep into your code, I'd say if you try and make it

```
for (var i = 0; i < subMenuItemsArray.length; i++) {
    (function () {
        var k = i;

         MenuItemsArray[k].addEventListener('click', function () { toggleClassname(null, true) }, false);
    }()); // immediate invocation
}
```

That should work.

Comment: That won't make any difference because neither `i` nor `k` is referenced in the event handler.