# How do I assign a " selected='selected' " attribute to a specific <option> in a <select> list. VanillaJS only please

Tags: javascript, html

Click the about menu button to see the "About" display in the select list. 
  I'd like each option match the clicked button.

```
<select name="selectList" id="mySelect">
     <option value="one">Home</option>
     <option value="two">About</option>
     <option value="three">Hobbies</option>
     <option value="four">Blog</option>
     <option value="five">Contact</option>
</select>

<nav>
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hobbies</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

var nav = document.getElementById("nav");
var mySelect = document.getElementById("mySelect");

for (i = 0; i < nav.children.length;i++) {
    nav.children[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      mySelect[1].selected='selected';
    })
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [addEventListener using for loop and passing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19586137/addeventlistener-using-for-loop-and-passing-values)

Answer (score 0):

When you add the event listener, on the function add a parameter. This will contain the event.

The `event.target` contains the element that has fired the event, so you can do `event.target.setAttribute("selected", "selected")`

For example:

```
nav.children[i].addEeventListener("click", function(event){
    event.target.setAttribute("selected", "selected");
});
```

PD: Don't forget to `removeAttribute` from the other items

Comment: But the event target will not be the associated `<option>`.

Answer (score 0):

THe problem is within the way you register your event listeners. You do it inside a loop. This is **wrong**. Event listening is asynchronous, which means that the listeners are really going to work after the current loop is over. (Same goes for any async activity, including `setTimeout`. Just try using a `setTimeout` inside a loop and you will see how it behaves - it won't be the way you expected!) And when the loop is over, the value of `i` is going to be 5, and there is no option with index 5. Here is another way of registering listeners, if you are okay with writing in in the html.

```js
var nav = document.getElementById("nav");
    var mySelect = document.getElementById("mySelect");

    function onNavClick(index) {
        mySelect.children[index].selected = 'selected';
    }
```

```html
<select name="selectList" id="mySelect">
    <option value="one">Home</option>
    <option value="two">About</option>
    <option value="three">Hobbies</option>
    <option value="four">Blog</option>
    <option value="five">Contact</option>
</select>


<nav>
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#" onclick="onNavClick(0)">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="onNavClick(1)">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="onNavClick(2)">Hobbies</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="onNavClick(3)">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="onNavClick(4)">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: While this may solve the problem, it's worth considering "unobtrusive JavaScript", particularly "[separation of behavior from markup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript#Separation_of_behavior_from_markup)".

Answer (score 0):

You could check the `textContent` of the `target` element of the event to check if the values match the options and select the one you want. Here is a snippet:

```js
var nav = document.getElementById("nav");
var mySelect = document.getElementById("mySelect");

for (var i = 0; i < nav.children.length; i++) {
  nav.children[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    var text = e.target.textContent;
    var options = mySelect.getElementsByTagName('option');
    for (var j = 0; j < options.length; j++) {
      var option = options[j];
      if (option.text === text) {
        option.selected = 'selected';
      } else {
        option.selected = null;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<select name="selectList" id="mySelect">
  <option value="one">Home</option>
  <option value="two">About</option>
  <option value="three">Hobbies</option>
  <option value="four">Blog</option>
  <option value="five">Contact</option>
</select>


<nav>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Hobbies</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: While this solves the problem, I have to say this is one horrible piece of code. You rely on the `textContent` of the nav buttons to equal to the `textContent` of the `option`, which is not guaranteed to always be the same (I mean on the long distance). And you have a loop inside a loop for just registering event listener, and you trigger a DOM search and another loop for just changing a `selected` attribute.

Comment: I agree about using `textContent` to match the options, but since the values of the `option` don't match the text I think it was the simplest way to check. I could use some data attributes but I would have to change the html markup. About registering the events, it is the way to do when registering an event listener to multiple elements using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

By the time a click event fires, the loop has already run its course.
Since the variable `i` is in global scope, the value referenced from each handler will be the same.
In the example below, notice that each handler references last value in the loop (5):

```js
var mySelect = document.getElementById("mySelect");

for (i = 0; i < nav.children.length; i++) {
  nav.children[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(i);
  })
};
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Hobbies</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

One technique is to use a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).
For reference, also see [Creating Closures in Loops - A Common Mistake](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops_A_common_mistake).

```js
var nav = document.getElementById("nav");
var mySelect = document.getElementById("mySelect");

var selectOption = function(index) {
  return function() {
    mySelect.children[index].selected = 'selected';
  }
}

for (i = 0; i < nav.children.length; i++) {
  nav.children[i].addEventListener("click", selectOption(i));
};
```

```html
<select name="selectList" id="mySelect">
  <option value="one">Home</option>
  <option value="two">About</option>
  <option value="three">Hobbies</option>
  <option value="four">Blog</option>
  <option value="five">Contact</option>
</select>

<nav>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Hobbies</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

---

Another technique is to use the [`let` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let):

> **let** allows you to declare variables that are limited in scope to the block, statement, or expression on which it is used. This is unlike the var keyword, which defines a variable globally, or locally to an entire function regardless of block scope.

```js
var nav = document.getElementById("nav");
var mySelect = document.getElementById("mySelect");

for (i = 0; i < nav.children.length; i++) {
  let option = mySelect[i];
  nav.children[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    option.selected = 'selected';
  });
};
```

```html
<select name="selectList" id="mySelect">
  <option value="one">Home</option>
  <option value="two">About</option>
  <option value="three">Hobbies</option>
  <option value="four">Blog</option>
  <option value="five">Contact</option>
</select>

<nav>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Hobbies</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses a closure to preserve the intended value of `i` for each of the event listeners; and `selectedIndex` to set the select box option (which in this case is somewhat more convenient than setting the selected attribute on one of the `<option>`s.)   It's otherwise identical to your code.

```js
var nav = document.getElementById("nav");
var mySelect = document.getElementById("mySelect");

for (i = 0; i < nav.children.length; i++) {
  (function(i) { // begin closure
    nav.children[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      mySelect.selectedIndex = i; // easier way to set the selected option
    });
  })(i); // end of the closure
};
```

```html
<select name="selectList" id="mySelect">
     <option value="one">Home</option>
     <option value="two">About</option>
     <option value="three">Hobbies</option>
     <option value="four">Blog</option>
     <option value="five">Contact</option>
</select>


<nav>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Hobbies</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla remove and add selected attribute

```
for (var j = 0; j < event.options.length; j++) {
    var option =  event.options[j];
    if(j==event.selectedIndex) {
        option.setAttribute("selected","selected");
    }else{
        option.removeAttribute('selected');
    }
}
```