# Issue with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, dom

So I'm applying my recent knowledge of Javascript and the DOM. However, I'm getting an error message saying "addEventListener is not defined" when I attempt to use querySelectorAll or getElementsByClassName for the same button, but for different questions. Here's my code block.

```
var input = document.getElementsByClassName('userInput');
var submitButton = document.getElementsByClassName('.submit');
var numAnsCorrect = 0;
var numAnsIncorrect = 0;
var questionsRight = document.querySelector('.questionsRight');
var questionsWrong = document.querySelector('.questionsWrong');


submitButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let submitButton = document.querySelector('.submit');
    let userInput = document.querySelector('.userInput');
    let response = userInput.value;
    response = response.toUpperCase();
    var answer = ['SAVANNAH', 'NATHAN DEAL'];
    let result = document.querySelector('.question-result');
    for (var i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
        if (response === answer[i]) {
            result.textContent += ' That is correct!';
            numAnsCorrect++;
            questionsRight.textContent = numAnsCorrect;
            submitButton.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            result.textContent += ' That is incorrect';
            numAnsIncorrect++;
            questionsWrong.textContent = numAnsIncorrect;
            submitButton.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong? I assumed I would have to loop through the buttons or maybe have another equality operator for button but I'm not too sure.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a HTML List not a single element

Answer (score 1):

When you use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) or [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), you get a list of Elements back. You need to pull an element out of that list to be able to call `addEventListener()` on it.

example:

```
var userInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('userInput');
var input = userInputs[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't be 100% certain with what's wrong with the OP code since HTML isn't provided, *but* I can safely assume that there a number elements you want to be listening for events. There are a couple of ways to meet your objective:

1. Use a loop or an array method to iterate through multiple elements. [On each loop assign an event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19586183/2813224) on the current element.

   ```
   for (let i=0; i < list.length; i++) {
     list[i].addEventListener('click', eventHandler);
   }
   ```
2. Assign an [on event attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers) to each element.

   ```
   <button onclick='eventHandler()'>CLICK</button>
   <button onclick='eventHandler()'>CLICK</button>
   ```
3. [**Event Delegation**](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm) is a pattern that takes advantage of [Event Bubbling](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing), and the [Event Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event). Basically if there's a group of elements that we need to listen for events, we simply assign **one eventListener** to an ancestor element that the group of elements have in common (we can even use `document` or `window`.) In doing so, our resources are not tied up in several eventHandlers / eventListeners and we don't get Carpal Tunnel Syndrome typing in 100 onclick events.⭐ **Recommended**

---

### Demo 1

#### Registering eventHamdlers/eventListeners on on each iteration of a NodeList or an array

---

```js
/* Collect all .btn class in a NodeList then convert it into
|| an array
*/
var btnArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.btn'));

// Reference the output.out
var out = document.querySelector('.out');

/* run arry through forEach() array method...
|| on each loop assign an onclick eventHandler or eventListener to
|| current button.btn
*/
btnArray.forEach(function(btn, idx) {

  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {

    var txt = btn.textContent;

    out.textContent = txt;
    
  });

});
```

```css
.out,
button {
  display: inline-block;
  color: blue;
  font: 900 20px/1 Consolas;
  width: 5ch;
  text-align: center;
}

.out {
  color: red;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px
}
```

```html
<fieldset class='set'>
  <button class='btn'>BTN0</button>
  <button class='btn'>BTN1</button>
  <button class='btn'>BTN2</button>
  <button class='btn'>BTN3</button>
  <button class='btn'>BTN4</button>
  <button class='btn'>BTN5</button>
  <button class='btn'>BTN6</button>
  <button class='btn'>BTN7</button>
  <button class='btn'>BTN8</button>
  <button class='btn'>BTN9</button>
  <button class='btn'>BTNA</button>
  <button class='btn'>BTNB</button>
  <button class='btn'>BTNC</button>
  <button class='btn'>BTND</button>
  <button class='btn'>BTNE</button>
  <button class='btn'>BTNF</button>
  <output class='out'>X</output>
</fieldset>
```

---

### Demo 2

#### Assign an on event attribute on each element

---

```js
var out = document.querySelector('.out');

function eventHandler(event) {
  var txt = event.target.textContent;
  out.value = txt;
}
```

```css
.out,
button {
  display: inline-block;
  color: blue;
  font: 900 20px/1 Consolas;
  width: 5ch;
  text-align: center;
}

.out {
  color: red;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px
}
```

```html
<fieldset class='set'>
  <button class='btn' onclick="eventHandler(event,this)">BTN0</button>
  <button class='btn' onclick="eventHandler(event,this)">BTN1</button>
  <button class='btn' onclick="eventHandler(event,this)">BTN2</button>
  <button class='btn' onclick="eventHandler(event,this)">BTN3</button>
  <button class='btn' onclick="eventHandler(event,his)">BTN4</button>
  <button class='btn' onclick="eventHandler(event,this)">BTN5</button>
  <button class='btn' onclick="eventHandler(event,this)">BTN6</button>
  <button class='btn' onclick="eventHandler(event,this)">BTN7</button>
  <button class='btn' onclick="eventHandler(event,this)">BTN8</button>
  <button class='btn' onclick="eventHandler(event,this)">BTN9</button>
  <button class='btn' onclick="eventHandler(event,this)">BTNA</button>
  <button class='btn' onclick="eventHandler(event,this)">BTNB</button>
  <button class='btn' onclick="eventHandler(event,this)">BTNC</button>
  <button class='btn' onclick="eventHandler(event,this)">BTND</button>
  <button class='btn' onclick="eventHandler(event,this)">BTNE</button>
  <button class='btn' onclick="eventHandler(event,this)">BTNF</button>
  <output class='out'>X</output>
</fieldset>
```

---

### Demo 3

#### Event Delegation

**Details commented in Demo**

⭐ **Recommended**

---

```js
// Reference the parent element
var set = document.querySelector('.set');

/* Register parent to click event it will trigger not only when 
|| it is clicked, it will also trigger callback if any of ts 
|| descebdant elements are clicked as well.
*/
set.addEventListener('click', eventHandler);

// Callback function passes the Event Object
function eventHandler(even) {

  // Reference an output.out
  var out = document.querySelector('.out');

  // if the clicked element (event.target) has the class .btn...
  if (event.target.className === "btn") {

    // ...Get event.target's text
    var txt = event.target.textContent;

    // Display the text
    out.value = txt;
  }

  return false;

};
```

```css
.out,
button {
  display: inline-block;
  color: blue;
  font: 900 20px/1 Consolas;
  width: 5ch;
  text-align: center;
}

.out {
  color: red;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px
}
```

```html
<fieldset class='set'>
  <button class='btn'>BTN0</button>
  <button class='btn'>BTN1</button>
  <button class='btn'>BTN2</button>
  <button class='btn'>BTN3</button>
  <button class='btn'>BTN4</button>
  <button class='btn'>BTN5</button>
  <button class='btn'>BTN6</button>
  <button class='btn'>BTN7</button>
  <button class='btn'>BTN8</button>
  <button class='btn'>BTN9</button>
  <button class='btn'>BTNA</button>
  <button class='btn'>BTNB</button>
  <button class='btn'>BTNC</button>
  <button class='btn'>BTND</button>
  <button class='btn'>BTNE</button>
  <button class='btn'>BTNF</button>
  <output class='out'>X</output>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: That's what I was trying to do - loop through the input fields and then compare each answer to an index in an array called 'answers'. Let me try to paste my HTML in the comment below.

Comment: So it's not letting me paste code here, but what I had was an ol with each li having an input field and submit button. In that case would I have to set up 2 different loops to get the answer or try to incorporate them into one?

Comment: You should really consider using Demo 3. in Demo 3 all you need to do is determine `e.target`, setup and use **ONE EVENTLISTENER()** for any number of elements, no loops, you don't even need to know any IDs or classes.

Answer (score -1):

I have this issue before. Try console.log on **submitButton** . But the best to fetch DOM element is by getElementsById in some cases. Or use JQuery for advanced purpose.

Comment: jQuery is a virus that needs to be eradicated.