# Cannot return JavaScript nested callback function inner function return value

Tags: javascript

I'm still trying to get back from a nested callback function inner functions return value but already I ran out of ideas.

Here is the code:

```
function addListener() {
  var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName('img');
  var ids = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
  for (let i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    let img = imgs[i];
    img.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var card_1 = function getId() {
        var Id = ids[i].id;
        return Id;
      };
      img.style.opacity = "1.0";
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        img.style.opacity = "0.0"
      }, 2000)
    });
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What specific error or issue are you having with this code? Is the problem the image opacity is NOT changing but should? Or are you trying to return something here?

Comment: You are selecting ids and imgs by class name, are you sure about it?

Comment: You've defined a variable called `card_1` but never used it. Is that an oversight or is it part of the question?

Comment: Read about closures

Comment: There are images inside divs and I would like to get the divs id which contains the image when I clicked on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [addEventListener using for loop and passing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19586137/addeventlistener-using-for-loop-and-passing-values)

Comment: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: This question is hard to understand with code that doesn't make too much sense. Why are you declaring a function and never calling it? What are you hoping to do? When do you want the id of the clicked element?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to use a callback, you cannot return a value from this function, because the work the function does is asynchronous:

```
function addListener(cb) {
  var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName('img');
  var ids = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
  for (let i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    let img = imgs[i];
    var Id = ids[i].id;
    img.addEventListener('click', function() {
        cb(null,Id);         // use an error-first callback
      img.style.opacity = "1.0";
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        img.style.opacity = "0.0"
      }, 2000)
    });
  }
}
```

call the function like so:

```
addListener(function(err,id){

});
```