# How can I shorten my code with for() or something else in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

**WHAT I WANT TO DO**

I want to shorten my code.
This Drum Play App plays sound by pressing certain keys or clicking with your mouse.

It works, but the code for click events is too long because I repeated the same code many times.

Could anyone make it cleaner/shorter?

**WHAT I TRIED**

I tried for loop, like below:

```
document.querySelector(`div[data-key="${dataKeys[i]}"]`).addEventListener...
```

But it didn't work.

**MY CURRENT CODE**

Here is my code.

```html
<body>

  <div class="keys">
    <div data-key="65" class="key">
      <kbd>A</kbd>
      <span class="sound">clap</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="83" class="key">
      <kbd>S</kbd>
      <span class="sound">hihat</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="68" class="key">
      <kbd>D</kbd>
      <span class="sound">kick</span>
    </div>
    ...

  </div>

  <audio data-key="65" src="sounds/clap.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="83" src="sounds/hihat.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="68" src="sounds/kick.wav"></audio>
  ...

<script>
  window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
    if (!audio) return; // Stop the function from running all together
    audio.currentTime = 0; // Rewind to the start
    audio.play();
  });

  document.querySelector('div[data-key="65"]').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log('I clicked.')
    const clickedAudio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="65"]`);
    clickedAudio.currentTime = 0; // Rewind to the start
    clickedAudio.play();
  });

  document.querySelector('div[data-key="83"]').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log('I clicked.')
    const clickedAudio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="83"]`);
    clickedAudio.currentTime = 0; // Rewind to the start
    clickedAudio.play();
  });

  document.querySelector('div[data-key="68"]').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log('I clicked.')
    const clickedAudio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="68"]`);
    clickedAudio.currentTime = 0; // Rewind to the start
    clickedAudio.play();
  });
  ...

</script>

</body>
```

---

I'd appreciate it if anyone could make my code cleaner or shorter.

Comment: Well asked question +1

Comment: You can add a common class to all the `divs` and access the clicked class using `this` variable

Comment: The reason you can't attach listeners in a loop is due to closures. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19586137/addeventlistener-using-for-loop-and-passing-values) thread.

Comment: Use `e.getAttribute( 'data-key' );` the same way you use `e.keyCode`. That way you can have one click function for all the divs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select all `.key` elements, check their dataset to get their associated key number, and then you can dynamically select the associated `audio`:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.key').forEach((div) => {
  div.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const { key } = div.dataset;
    const clickedAudio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${key}"]`);
    clickedAudio.currentTime = 0; // Rewind to the start
    clickedAudio.play();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Your code works well!
Let me ask one more question. What does this line mean? : const { key } = div.dataset;

Comment: That's destructuring. It extracts the `key` property of the `dataset` object and puts it into a variable named `key`.