# Background Color is not changing

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

This is my code and when I am clicking on the button (btnColor) it is only showing last color in an array and not working

```
var color = ["#222F3E","#F368E0","#EE5253","#ABDE3","#10AC84","#222F3E","#5F27CD","pink"];
var btnColor = document.getElementById("color_change");


btnColor.addEventListener("click", function() {

    for(var i = 0; i < color.length; i++) {
        document.querySelector("body").style.background = color[i];
    }
})
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: The listener function goes through the entire loop. You need to put a counter outside the closure and use that for the color index. Also, you can add 1 to the counter on each click inside the closure to move it along the colors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [addEventListener using for loop and passing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19586137/addeventlistener-using-for-loop-and-passing-values)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 1):

It is cycling through all the colors, but it's happening immediately when you press the button.

To clarify: It cycles through everything, but it happens too fast for you to see.

If you want to make the background cycle once when you press the button, use the following code.

```
var color = ["#222F3E","#F368E0","#EE5253","#ABDE3","#10AC84","#222F3E","#5F27CD","pink"];
var btnColor = document.getElementById("color_change");
var colorI = 0;

btnColor.addEventListener("click", function() {

    document.querySelector("body").style.background = color[colorI];
    colorI++;
    colorI = colorI % color.length;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of a loop, add a variable `colorIndex` and increment it after each time the button is clicked, and check if you reach the end, reset it to `0` :

```js
var color = ["#222F3E", "#F368E0", "#EE5253", "#ABDE3", "#10AC84", "#222F3E", "#5F27CD", "pink"];
var btnColor = document.getElementById("color_change");

var colorIndex = 0;

btnColor.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (colorIndex === color.length) colorIndex = 0;
  document.querySelector("body").style.background = color[colorIndex++];

})
```

```html
<button id="color_change">Click me</button>
```