# Javascript loop funtion(i)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a rookie. I try this example to test code that when click on each p ,the section text will replace by "yeah"
When click first p, first section is replaced
When click 2nd p, 2nd section is replaced ...
Code like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
<style>p{text-align: center;}</style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="test">hello</p>
<p class="test">how</p>
<p class="test">are</p>
<p class="test">you</p>
<p class="test">today</p>
<p class="test">sir</p>
<section>good</section>
<section>great</section>
<section>excellent</section>
<section>well</section>
<section>best</section>
<section>better</section>
<script>
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("test")
var y = document.getElementsByTagName("section")
for(i=0;i<y.length;i++){
 y[i].setAttribute("class","linktest")
}
var z = document.getElementsByClassName("linktest")
function place(a){
 z[a-1].innerHTML="yeah"
}

for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){
 x[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
place(i+1)})
}

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

> how i wrong with for loop code of addEventListener
>   I try to write long code like this

```
x[0].addEventListener("click",function(){place(1)})
x[1].addEventListener("click",function(){place(2)})
x[2].addEventListener("click",function(){place(3)})
x[3].addEventListener("click",function(){place(4)})
x[4].addEventListener("click",function(){place(5)})
x[5].addEventListener("click",function(){place(6)})
```

And it worked but i want to short code because real work has mor than 100 items
Help plz

Comment: Does this answer your question? [addEventListener using for loop and passing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19586137/addeventlistener-using-for-loop-and-passing-values)

Answer (score 1):

@Chaska's answer works fine but since you mentioned that there will be **over 100 items** it's important to avoid adding event listeners for each element for better performance. Instead wrap all the `p` tags in a `div` and add a single event listener to the `div` tag. Here is a slightly modified code.

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
var y = document.getElementsByTagName("section");
for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
  //assuming equal no. of elements in x and y
  y[i].setAttribute("class", "linktest");
  x[i].setAttribute('data-index', i);
}
var z = document.getElementsByClassName("linktest");

function place(a) {
  z[a].innerHTML = "yeah";
}

var testGroup = document.getElementById('test-group');
testGroup.addEventListener('click', function() {
  place(parseInt(event.target.getAttribute('data-index')));
})
```

```html
<div id="test-group">
  <p class="test">hello</p>
  <p class="test">how</p>
  <p class="test">are</p>
  <p class="test">you</p>
  <p class="test">today</p>
  <p class="test">sir</p>
</div>


<section>good</section>
<section>great</section>
<section>excellent</section>
<section>well</section>
<section>best</section>
<section>better</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `place()` function out of the for loop. So the value of `i` will always be `6`.

Try this way to assign the index to each element first and pass it to the `place()` function.

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
var y = document.getElementsByTagName("section");
for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
  y[i].setAttribute("class", "linktest");
}
var z = document.getElementsByClassName("linktest");

function place(a) {
  z[a].innerHTML = "yeah";
}

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].setAttribute('data-index', i);
  x[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    place(parseInt(this.getAttribute('data-index')));
  })
}
```

```html
<p class="test">hello</p>
<p class="test">how</p>
<p class="test">are</p>
<p class="test">you</p>
<p class="test">today</p>
<p class="test">sir</p>
<section>good</section>
<section>great</section>
<section>excellent</section>
<section>well</section>
<section>best</section>
<section>better</section>
```