# Targeting an specific row to make an accordion arrow spin in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, accordion, target

Hi im working on animating an arrow in an accordion but it only animates the first row no matter which one i pick. I know its a target issue but can make this work. some help would be great!!

code pen here https://codepen.io/al-web-dev/pen/bGRXdyL

```
<div class="myDiv">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">Test</div>
                <div class="col-4 cheese">test 1</div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">Test</div>
                <div class="col-4 cheese">test 2</div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


   var myDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("row");

for (var i = 0; i < myDiv.length; i++) {
    myDiv[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        let toggleAble = document.querySelector(".fa-arrow-up");
        let cheese = document.querySelector(".cheese");
        event.target.classList.toggle("yello");
        event.target.classList.toggle("arrow-down");
    });
}
```

Comment: You're adding an event listener in a loop. Use a closure. Check out this answer for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19586137/addeventlistener-using-for-loop-and-passing-values

Comment: Look good but im struggling to see how this can be translated onto my code.. is it a targeting issue? Do i need to use 'bind'

Answer (score 0):

The code in your codepen and your example given here is different. I suggest settling on one version of the code if you're gonna ask for help.

The problem you were facing in your codepen example had to do with `var toggleAble`. You were query-selecting by a classname. `.querySelector` will only pick the first element from a list of elements it finds. That is why you've had only the first arrow react. Change `document` before your query selector method to `myDiv[i]` - the element you're looking for the arrow in. Like so:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < myDiv.length; i++) {
  myDiv[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    var toggleAble = myDiv[i].querySelector(".fa-arrow-up");
    toggleAble.classList.toggle("arrow-down");
  });
}
```

Oh and for some reason you've renamed the function parameter to `myDiv`, an already declared array of elements. I've changed it back to `event` for you.

Comment: @slidejoe appreciate your help!