# How to select a clicked button form list of buttons with the same class names in js?

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

I was working with some javascript code and i have a list of buttons with the same class names but i wanted to know which button among them is clicked inorder to get the value. How can I do that with vanilla js? Here is the sample code

```
<button onclick="chooseRating()" id="rateBtn" class="rateBtn" value="1">1</button>
<button onclick="chooseRating()" id="rateBtn" class="rateBtn"value="2">2</button>
<button onclick="chooseRating()" id="rateBtn" class="rateBtn"value="3">3</button>
<button onclick="chooseRating()" id="rateBtn" class="rateBtn"value="4">4</button>
<button onclick="chooseRating()" id="rateBtn" class="rateBtn"value="5">5</button>
```

and the js code i tried is

```
const rateBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("rateBtn");
function chooseRating() {
    for (rate in rateBtn) {
        console.log(rateBtn[rate]);
        if (rateBtn[rate].clicked === true) {
            rating = rateBtn[rate].value;
            console.log(rating);
            //shows 5 don't know why
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's showing 5 because [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19586137/addeventlistener-using-for-loop-and-passing-values), but your code has other issues.

Answer (score 2):

You should first of all define a unique *id* per button.

Additionally, you can pass the HTML element to your onClick method as a parameter.

So for example:

```
<button onclick="chooseRating(this)" id="rateBtn1" class="rateBtn" value="1">1</button>
<button onclick="chooseRating(this)" id="rateBtn2" class="rateBtn" value="2">2</button>
<button onclick="chooseRating(this)" id="rateBtn3" class="rateBtn" value="3">3</button>
<button onclick="chooseRating(this)" id="rateBtn4" class="rateBtn" value="4">4</button>
<button onclick="chooseRating(this)" id="rateBtn5" class="rateBtn" value="5">5</button>
```

You can then from vanilla javascript code get the ID and the value of your HTML button:

```
function chooseRating(e) {
    console.log(`my ID is ${e.id}, and my value is ${e.value}`);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass on a variable to the function-call in each button.
EXAMPLE:
onclick="myFunction(variable)"

HTML-file:

```
   <button onclick="myFunction(value)" id="rateBtn" class="rateBtn" value="1">
    1
  </button>
  <button onclick="myFunction(value)" id="rateBtn" class="rateBtn" value="2">
    2
  </button>
  <button onclick="myFunction(value)" id="rateBtn" class="rateBtn" value="3">
    3
  </button>
  <button onclick="myFunction(value)" id="rateBtn" class="rateBtn" value="4">
    4
  </button>
  <button onclick="myFunction(value)" id="rateBtn" class="rateBtn" value="5">
    5
  </button>
```

JavaScript-file:

```
function myFunction(val) { console.log(val); }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).